# Rename [online-radar] to [online-tracking]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Could [online-radar](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-radar) be renamed to [online-tracking](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-tracking) without having to retag questions? Or create [online-tracking](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-tracking) and create a synonym?

Comment: On the surface this seems pretty sensible to me - I'd say [tag:online-tracking] <- [tag:online-radar] would be the right way o go?

Comment: @voretaq7 I cannot interpret the intention of your `<-` there. Did you mean you wanted to create a new tag and then a synonym to the new tag?

Comment: Yeah, create the online tracking tag, and synonym online-radar to it (which will also mass-retag things).  (The `<-` is the way the tag synonym page shows these things - "master" tag on the left, because... idunno, Think Different? :-/)

Comment: @voretaq7 I have created [tag:online-tracking]. Feel free to create the synonym link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

✔ Synonym Created

[image: Stack ExchangeMission Accomplished]